# determine distribution function from density function

Tags: statistics, functions

The variable $\xi$ has the following density function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x/50&0<x<10\\
0&else\end{cases}$$

How do I determine its distribution function?

Comment: Can I learn from that question that frequency function is another description for density function?

Comment: Yes thats probably the correct name for it. I took for granted that the name would be similar to my language's name of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the CDF by integrating $f(x)$:
$$F(x) = \int_0^xf(s)\;ds = \int_0^x\frac{s}{50}\;ds=\frac{x^2}{100},\qquad 0<x<10$$
You can write
$$F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x\leq 0\\
\frac{x^2}{100} & 0<x<10 \\
1 & x \geq 10
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What steps are you taking when you go from $s/50$ to $x^2/100$

Comment: @Elias Have you learned how to take integrals? I just integrated $\frac{s}{50}$ and evaluated the result at the integration limits $x$ and $0$.

Comment: Ahh now I got it. I'm very new to it and it looked so different from what I'm used to but now I see how I would create and antiderivative

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) follows as :

$$F_X(x) = P\{X\leq x\} = \int_{-\infty}^xf_X(x)dx =\int_{-\infty}^xf(s)ds =\int_{0}^{x}\frac{s}{50}ds$$

Comment: The upper limit in your last integral should not be $10$. That would give you $F(10)$ and not $F(x)$. It also does not look nice to have $x$ as both an integration limit and the integration variable.